# NoClassDefFoundError - Android 2.3.X

Tags: android, android-asynctask, noclassdeffounderror

I have a Task defined in a class.
Fatal exception "NoClassDefFoundError" is happening on following line

```
MyCuteTask myTask = new MyCuteTask(equations)
```

Here is the code

```
public class MyClass  {

    public void run() {
        MyCuteTask myTask = new MyCuteTask(equations)
    }

    protected class MyCuteTask extends  AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        ...
    }
}
```

Recently, I have strange bug reports.
Android throw an exception when I instantiate my task.
I have this bug with android 2.3.X only.

Do any of you got the same bug?

EDIT: Here is the stack Trace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mathssolver.main.k
   at com.mathssolver.main.Logic.updateGraph(Logic.java:310)
   at com.mathssolver.main.Graph.update(Graph.java:249)
   at com.mathssolver.main.MathGraphFragment.plotFunction(MathGraphFragment.java:236)
   at com.mathssolver.main.MathGraphFragment.plot(MathGraphFragment.java:158)
   at com.mathssolver.main.MathGraphFragment.showExample(MathGraphFragment.java:141)
   at com.mathssolver.main.MathGraphFragment.onStart(MathGraphFragment.java:109)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1810)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:977)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:842)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.startPendingDeferredFragments(FragmentManager.java:1150)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1506)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8323)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8323)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8323)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8323)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8323)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8323)
   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:842)
   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1862)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mathssolver.main.k in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.shakti.mathssolver-1.apk]
   at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
   at com.mathssolver.main.Logic.updateGraph(Logic.java:310)
   at com.mathssolver.main.Graph.update(Graph.java:249)
   at com.mathssolver.main.MathGraphFragment.plotFunction(MathGraphFragment.java:236)
   at com.mathssolver.main.MathGraphFragment.plot(MathGraphFragment.java:158)
   at com.mathssolver.main.MathGraphFragment.showExample(MathGraphFragment.java:141)
   at com.mathssolver.main.MathGraphFragment.onStart(MathGraphFragment.java:109)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1810)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:977)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:842)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.startPendingDeferredFragments(FragmentManager.java:1150)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1506)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8323)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8323)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8323)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8323)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8323)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8323)
   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:842)
   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1862)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Line at com.mathssolver.main.Logic.updateGraph(Logic.java:310) is

```
 MyCuteTask myTask = new MyCuteTask(equations)
```

Comment: have you try to execute AsyncTask in UI thread ?

Comment: if you want to execute that Async task than just write following code.

    `new MyCuteTask.execute();`

this will execute your async task. don't create object of async task instead of that create object of your base class than try to access that async task.

Comment: So, you have error in Graph->Logic. You are usign here something from api 11+

Comment: @Suvitruf I have added stack trace also.

Comment: @ShaktiMalik pls, show code of Logic and Graph and copy line Logic.updateGraph(Logic.java:310)

Comment: @HareshChhelana Error comes at the line where I am instantiating this Async Task and not when i execute this. So I think it not because of that. Also I have't modified this code for long time and it was working fine so far. These errors started appearing after recent update.

Comment: @Suvitruf I have already added Logic.java:310 at the end of description.

Comment: @ShaktiMalik try to define MyCuteTask as static

Comment: @Suvitruf Could you please explain logic behind that ?

Comment: com.mathssolver.main.k is this a jar ?

Comment: i dont understand what what "k" class is...
in java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mathssolver.main.k. What IDE did you use for build?

Comment: Are you using proguard to obfuscate class names? `.k` looks like one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java explains the meaning of that exception, there seems to be a problem to load that class, it was probably found. I guess you don't have a device to reproduce that problem? Maybe you can see some error message at installation or run time in logcat that happen prior to this error.

Comment: Yes this error is happening in release build with proguard. I will try to test my app on android 2.3.x. I will retrace and find out what is com.mathssolver.main.k

Comment: @Suvitruf I am using Android Studio Rc1

Comment: Same error in google play! But most of my test 2.3.x devices is fine, so it may be a ADT build error. Please kindly let me know if you find some clues:)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/_x12qmjWI7M/8WkalST9hvUJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an google play services issue. (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81083)

Workaround to avoid this crash till Google fixes it:

Add following into your Application#onCreate() method

```
try {
  Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
}
catch(Throwable ignore) {
  // ignored
}
```

Note its Application#onCreate() and not Activity#onCreate()

Update: I can verify that above changes fixed these crashes for me.

Comment: Where can I find Application#onCreate()  for flutter?

Answer (score 0):

[Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) was added in API level 3. Please verify one by checking the same code with API 3. If it disappears, there is your problem

Comment: As I mentioned above I am seeing these errors at android 2.3.x

Answer (score 0):

This is an inner class please refer how to access the inner class object through outerclass else define your Myclass outside the Mainclass

Answer (score 0):

I reported the same error here: [Android: NoClassDefFoundError android.os.AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121376/android-noclassdeffounderror-android-os-asynctask)
Because it started happening without any app delivery it looks like yet another Google Play Services bug...
I'm having 83% of crashes on Android 2.3.x and 16% on crashes on 4.0.3 & 4.0.4

Comment: For me, all of the crashes are on android 2.3.x. I am not sure how can it be related to GooglePlayServices because AnsycTask is not part of GooglePlayServices.

Comment: Yes I know it's part of the Android SDK, but this is the only that has changed on the user device. My app hasn't been updated, they didn't get any Android update, only the new version of the Google Play Services has just been pushed, and almost everytime it comes with some strange bug...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I have copied source code of the AsyncTask as MyAsyncTask into my project and extended from that class, now it works.